# How to draw an N*N grid on the screen that completely fills the window by using "Processing"

Tags: java, processing

How to draw an N*N grid on the screen that completely fills the window.
Suppose n=8.

My code is like that:

```
boolean[][] rects;
void setup ()
{
size(300,300);
rects = new boolean[100][100];
fill(0);

}

void draw (){
  background(255);
  for (int r=0; r<100; r++ ){
    for ( int c = 0; c < 100; c++ ){
      if ( rects[r][c] == true ){
        rect( r*3, c*3, 3, 3 );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

when I run this code I just get a blank white screen. Am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  There is not enough here for us to be able to answer.  Please create a [Minimal, **Complete** and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @JoeC Please note the [tag:processing] tag. This is an MCVE.

Comment: More questions like the last one and you risk being put under a question ban. For future reference, please have a look at [Jon Skeet's StackOverflow Question Checklist](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). It's an abbreviated version of his wonderful longer post on [Writing the Perfect Question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Follow it and your the reception that your questions receive will improve as will the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this line:

```
rects = new boolean[100][100];
```

This creates a 100x100 2d array of `boolean` values, but they all have the default value of `false` because you haven't set them to anything.

Then check out this line:

```
if ( rects[r][c] == true ){
    rect( r*3, c*3, 3, 3 );
}
```

Here you're checking whether a particular index is `true`, but you haven't set them to anything other than the default of `false`. In other words, this `if` statement never evaluates to `true`, so your `rect()` function is never called.

You need to set some of the `boolean` values to `true` for this code to do anything.

```
rects = new boolean[100][100];
rects[50][50] = true;
```